# Create new MX records for Google Apps Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm very new to all things web-development. I have a website registered with Route 53 and am using Amazon Web Services to host the content. I am trying to use Google Apps for Work to get email addresses using the domain, and it's asking me to edit the MX records. I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do and where I'm supposed to do it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

- Login to the Route 53 Console
- Select your domain name and click "Go To Record Sets"
- Click "Create Record Set"
- Leave **Name** empty
- For **Type** select **MX**
- For **Value** copy and paste the following.

```html
1  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5  ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Make sure that the domains end in a period "." to ensure it's treated as a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name)

Source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en

Comment: Thank you imperalix - I was having the name with @, which was problematic

Comment: I cant get past this error 
The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.

Comment: @mindmyweb you have to copy past mx record names with begining numbers  *1  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.* *5  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.* i tryed just now it wokred for me. before i was pasting to aws route 53 without begining 1,510,.. numbers

Comment: Is it one line for each value or is it the whole thing in one value?

Comment: Great! Thanks! Also note mentioning do not forget to put the "." at the end of ".com". Was an issue on my side.